# Certain Subset of Sorgenfrey Plane is Closed

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

Note that $L = \{(x,-x) \mid x \in \Bbb{R} \}$ is closed. Then if $A$ is closed in $L$, then it will also be closed in $\Bbb{R}^2_\ell$. According to Munkres, $L-A$ will also be closed, but I am having trouble proving this. The set $L-A$ closed in $\Bbb{R}^2_\ell$ if and only if $\Bbb{R}^2_\ell - (L-A) = (\Bbb{R}^2_\ell - L) \cup A$ is open, which I am having trouble seeing the truth of this.

Comment: Try to think of what the general open sets look like on the Sorgenfrey plane. The sub space topology for the line you gave is the same as the discrete topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\{(x,x)\} = ([x,x+1) \times [x,x+1)) \cap L$, every singleton subset of $L$ is open in $L$ (as an intersection of an open set of the Sorgenfrey plane with $L$).

This means that $L$ is discrete as a subspace: all of its subsets are open (and thus closed) in $L$ and as $L$ is closed in the Sorgenfrey plane, all of its subsets are closed in the Sorgenfrey plane.